# Wrong translation in asp.net web service when connected from Android

Tags: asp.net, android, localization, translation

My Android app connects to a asp.net web service to register the user. When the user is registered I send a welcome email from the server to the user. As we have customers in many countries the email need to be translated into the right language. I use the following code (C#) on the server to get the body of the email:

```
string mailbody = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "mailbody");
```

In my App_GlobalResources-folder I have a file containing the English translation called Resource.resx and for the Swedish translation Resource.sv.resx.

Many English users are now complaining about that they get the Swedish translation sent instead of the English translation. Every time I test this on my Android phones I get the right translation so it is hard for me to track this error down. Also this has been working great when connected from iPhone. Any ideas what can be wrong? Have anyone seen a problem like this?

Comment: How are you determining which language they should be using?  Are you doing a Geo-IP lookup or asking the user which language they want?

Comment: I let asp.net decide based on the request, in my web.config I'm using <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" /> so that asp.net will use the right translation based on the language of the browser. Maybe that isn't working with Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describes seem pretty odd. It seems to be related to Culture detection in your web service and of course web.config might play a role here.
However, setting culture and uiCulture to "auto" should detect the most desired culture from web browser, that is I don't think it should be Swedish for English user... I would suspect some strange fall-back rule.
Are you really sure your neutral-culture resources (Resource.resx) are in English (just to double check that)?
Maybe you have some overrides in Global.asax?

If the answer for both question is "it's OK", maybe try to modify settings to uiCulture="auto:en-US" so that language falls back directly to English (United States). With no other resources and neutral culture resources in English, it should, but...

Comment: Yes the Resource.resx is in English, no overrides in Global.asax either. We have been using this web service on our website and iPhone app for over a year. The problems started when the Android app connects to the same service, but as I say I can't reproduce the problem, all I get is angry emails :) Setting uiCulture="auto:en-US" will that still show Swedish if my users are Swedish or will that always show English? Maybe I should try to add a Resource.en-US.resx also?

Comment: It should show Swedish if user's primary language is Swedish. Copying Resource.resx as Resource.en-US.resx also make some sense, although theoretically it should not make any difference.

Comment: Adding a Resource.en-US.resx also seems to do the trick. Haven't got any reports after adding this. Thanks for your help!